# C weird string output

Tags: c

I tried running this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    char full[40];

    printf("Your first name?: ");
    fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin);
    printf("your last name?: ");
    fgets(last, sizeof(last), stdin);
    first[strlen(first) - 1] = '\0';
    strcat(full, first);
    strcat(full, " ");
    strcat(full, last);
    printf("Your full name is: %s", full);
}
```

and the output returned was..

```
Your first name?: Daniel
your last name?: Jee
Your full name is: pA▒Daniel Jee
```

Can anyone tell me what this is?

Comment: What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: When you declared full, it may already have values in memory.  As you did not set all of the values to zero, the strcat concatenates the first name to the end.  You need to copy the first name into full name.  I would look up strncpy or strcpy as that may be some functions which is helpful (I would go with the strncpy to keep from corrupting memory with an overwrite..

Answer (score 4):

`full` is not initialized,

`strcat(full, first);` invokes undefined behavior.

Garbage contents is a mild form of undefined behavior.

You should instead use:

```
strcpy(full, first);
```

Or better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) { 
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    char full[40];

    printf("Your first name? ");
    if (!fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin))
        return 1;
    printf("your last name? ");
    if (!fgets(last, sizeof(last), stdin))
        return 1;
    first[strlen(first) - 1] = '\0';
    snprintf(full, sizeof full, "%s %s", first, last);
    printf("Your full name is: %s", full);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `full` most likely contains a trailing linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

Stack variables in C are not initialized. You did `strcat(full, first);` without first setting `full[0]=0;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably copy the first string into full instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    char full[40];

    printf ("Your first name?: ");
    fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin);
    printf("your last name?: ");
    fgets(last, sizeof(last), stdin);
    first[strlen(first) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(full, first);
    strcat(full, " ");
    strcat(full, last);
    printf ("Your full name is: %s", full);
}
```